# What's the replacement for the avcodec_thread_init?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-streaming

I am using ffmpeg to encode/decode videos.
I used a old version in the past, but recently I switched a new version and found that many ffmpeg functions are non-longer in use.

Here is my old code:

```
 pCodecCtx=pVideoStream->codec;
   pCodecCtx->codec_id = pOutputFormat->video_codec;
   pCodecCtx->codec_type = ffmpeg::AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO;

   pCodecCtx->bit_rate = Bitrate;
   pCodecCtx->width = getWidth();
   pCodecCtx->height = getHeight();
   pCodecCtx->time_base.den = fps;
   pCodecCtx->time_base.num = 1;
   pCodecCtx->gop_size = Gop;
   pCodecCtx->pix_fmt = ffmpeg::PIX_FMT_YUV420P;


   avcodec_thread_init(pCodecCtx, 10);

   //if (c->codec_id == CODEC_ID_MPEG2VIDEO)
   //{
      //c->max_b_frames = 2;  // just for testing, we also add B frames
   //}

   // some formats want stream headers to be separate
   if(pFormatCtx->oformat->flags & AVFMT_GLOBALHEADER)
      pCodecCtx->flags |= CODEC_FLAG_GLOBAL_HEADER;


   if (av_set_parameters(pFormatCtx, NULL) < 0)
   {
      printf("Invalid output format parameters\n");
      return false;
   }

   ffmpeg::dump_format(pFormatCtx, 0, fileName.toStdString().c_str(), 1);

   // open_video
   // find the video encoder
   pCodec = avcodec_find_encoder(pCodecCtx->codec_id);
   if (!pCodec)
   {
      printf("codec not found\n");
      return false;
   }
   // open the codec
   if (avcodec_open(pCodecCtx, pCodec) < 0)
   {
      printf("could not open codec\n");
      return false;
   }

   // Allocate memory for output
   if(!initOutputBuf())
   {
      printf("Can't allocate memory for output bitstream\n");
      return false;
   }

   // Allocate the YUV frame
   if(!initFrame())
   {
      printf("Can't init frame\n");
      return false;
   }

   if (url_fopen(&pFormatCtx->pb, fileName.toStdString().c_str(), URL_WRONLY) < 0)
   {
      printf( "Could not open '%s'\n", fileName.toStdString().c_str());
      return false;
   }

   av_write_header(pFormatCtx);
```

Here, `avcodec_thread_init` is no-longer in use and I cannot find anyhints about what function I should use to replace it? Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the information available in the ffmpeg site, this function is now automatically called as part of avcodec_open() function. Pl. refer to the below url which provides information on the same. 
https://ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-devel/2011-February/103341.html